# Highlight a text in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, object

i am developing an iOS application witch have multiples UIWebView. i would like to select and highlight a text in the webView, but i would like to store this selection to reselect the same text when the user relunch the app. How i can do this please ?

Comment: are you loading the content locally (html files) or from the net ?\

Answer (score 0):

Store it in user defaults and read them back on relaunch.
If the textfield has a tag property you could write/read the tag of the selection from user defaults

Example:

```
// access the user defaults for your app:
defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// write to user defaults
[defaults setInteger:myTextField.tag forKey:@"selectedFieldsTag"];

// read from user defaults (on launch?)
NSInteger selectedTag = [defaults integerForKey:@"selectedFieldsTag"];
```

EDIT:  The above will work fine for storing information and retrieving, but if you start storing more data than just a tag or so you may want to consider using core data or another means for storage/retrieval.  As far as finding what the user selects, that's far less trivial.  This link explains how it can be done:

http://zaldzbugz.posterous.com/how-to-mark-or-get-the-highlighted-string-ins

Comment: You should consider using Core Data instead.

Comment: it's not a textField but a UIWebView, how to get the selection and store it from UIWebView ?

Comment: Please edit your question to elaborate on what you are trying to do.  Does the user select/highlight text on a webpage in your UIWebView?  And you want that text to be highlighted still next time they launch the app?

Comment: thanks but it's not what i want, i would like to serialize the selection and restore it in javascript.